# Apple Watch - Watch Kit - Delegate method not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface, apple-watch

Ok so I am attempting to pass an int to another interface, edit the int and give it back to the original interface. I am trying to use a delegate to achieve this and I believe I have it setup correctly and it appears the method is not being called when its supposed to.

```
//
//  InterfaceController.h
//  DelegateTest WatchKit Extension
//
//  Created by Rohan Hodge on 20/10/2015.
//  Copyright © 2015 Hodge Development. All rights reserved.
//

#import <WatchKit/WatchKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "SecondController.h"

@interface InterfaceController : WKInterfaceController <DelegateTest>
{
    NSTimer *Update;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKInterfaceLabel      *FirstControllerLabel;
@property (nonatomic,assign) int FirstInteger;
@property (nonatomic,assign) int RecievedInteger;
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSString *PassString;


@end
```

---

```
//  InterfaceController.m
//  DelegateTest WatchKit Extension
//
//  Created by Rohan Hodge on 20/10/2015.
//  Copyright © 2015 Hodge Development. All rights reserved.
//

#import "InterfaceController.h"


@interface InterfaceController()

@end


@implementation InterfaceController
@synthesize FirstInteger;
@synthesize RecievedInteger;
@synthesize PassString;

- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
    [super awakeWithContext:context];

    // Configure interface objects here.
}
-(void)UpdateVoid
{
     self.FirstControllerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", FirstInteger];
}

- (void)willActivate {
    SecondController *interfaceController;
    interfaceController.delegate = self;
    Update = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self      selector:@selector(UpdateVoid) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
[super willActivate];
}

- (void)didDeactivate {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer   visible
    [super didDeactivate];
}

-(void)DelegateMethod:(int)ReturningInt
{
    [self popController];
    FirstInteger = ReturningInt;
    self.FirstControllerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", FirstInteger];
}
- (IBAction)UpButton {
    FirstInteger++;
     self.FirstControllerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", FirstInteger];
}

- (IBAction)DownButton {
    FirstInteger--;
    self.FirstControllerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", FirstInteger];
}
- (IBAction)PassDataButton {
    PassString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", FirstInteger];
    [self pushControllerWithName:@"SecondController" context:PassString];
}

@end
```

---

```
//
//  SecondController.h
//  DelegateTest
//
//  Created by Rohan Hodge on 20/10/2015.
//  Copyright © 2015 Hodge Development. All rights reserved.
//

#import <WatchKit/WatchKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

//This declaration of delegate.
@protocol DelegateTest <NSObject>

-(void) DelegateMethod:(int)ReturningInt;

@end

@interface SecondController : WKInterfaceController
{
    id delegate;

}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <DelegateTest> delegate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKInterfaceLabel *SecondLabel;
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSString *RecievedString;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int FirstReceivedInteger;

@end
```

---

```
//
//  SecondController.m
//  DelegateTest
//
//  Created by Rohan Hodge on 20/10/2015.
//  Copyright © 2015 Hodge Development. All rights reserved.
//

#import "SecondController.h"
#import "InterfaceController.h"

@interface SecondController ()

@end

@implementation SecondController
@synthesize SecondLabel;
@synthesize FirstReceivedInteger;
@synthesize RecievedString;
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;

- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
    [super awakeWithContext:context];

    //This is where I receive the int inside of a string and split it from the string so I can change it
   RecievedString = context;
   FirstReceivedInteger = [RecievedString intValue];


    // Configure interface objects here.
}

- (void)willActivate {
    self.SecondLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",FirstReceivedInteger];

    // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
    [super willActivate];
}


- (IBAction)UpButton {
    FirstReceivedInteger++;
    self.SecondLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",FirstReceivedInteger];
}
- (IBAction)DownButton {
    FirstReceivedInteger--;
    self.SecondLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",FirstReceivedInteger];
}
  //This is a button that is ment to pass back the int.
  - (IBAction)ReturnToOriginalInterface:(id)sender{

      [self.delegate DelegateMethod:FirstReceivedInteger];

 }

 - (void)didDeactivate {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
    [super didDeactivate];
 }
  @end
```

---

I'm new to Stack Overflow, Sorry about the messy code formatting.

P.S I use the Arrow in the top left of the interface to return to the original Interface. Also am using Objective-C

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a property or method to change in your controller (that your first controller will change) and you get back the result with a `delegate` pattern.

Comment: I am rather new to this and don't really know how they work, Could you point me towards a tutorial or explanation please?

Comment: http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html

Comment: you're welcome, it's a very basic pattern that you'll need all the time ;) so learn it by heart.

Comment: I don't mean to be a pain but I believe I have correctly setup my delegate but when I have adjusted the int I call the delegate which should send back the int, I then return back to to original interface but the int has not been changed. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: As far as I can tell, Its not actually calling the delegate method.

Comment: Sorry bro but it's too hard for me to give you answers, I clearly see that you are very very new to objective-C and probably coding too. It's normal, but I cannot answer a simple question here, it's too broad, I suggest you search for other delegate tutorial until you see how it works.

Comment: Haha Yea its all good, I'm new to objective-c and ios development in general but I have a bit of coding experience using c#. Thanks for the help anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to do this in a Watch app, yes? I don't know that delegates don't work, but when I did this for my Watch app, I used the `context` parameter of `WKInterfaceController::presentControllerWithName:context:`.

`context` is a NSDictionary of the values you want to pass around. One of those values could be a pointer to the presenting controller.

So, trying to decipher what you're attempting in your app, I believe the proper thing to do is:

In the **ORIGINAL** WKInterfaceController:

```
- (IBAction)buttonThatOpensOtherIC
{
    NSDictionary *context = @{
                              @"firstController" : self,
                              };

    [self pushControllerWithName:@"Other IC"
                         context:context];
    }
}
```

In the **OTHER** WKInterfaceController:

```
- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
    [super awakeWithContext:context];

    if (context)
    {
        self.originalInterfaceController = context[@"firstController"];
    }
}

//This is the button that calls the delegate method.
- (IBAction)ReturnToOriginalInterface:(id)sender
{
    // [self.delegate DelegateMethod:FirstReceivedInteger];

    if (self.originalInterfaceController) {
        self.originalInterfaceController.firstInteger = self.returningInt;
    }

    [self popController];
}
```

*Note the use of `awakeWithContext:` in the **OTHER** interface controller.

***DISCLAIMER #1:*** I haven't executed this code, so there may be a typo in it. It is an adaptation for you of working code I do use.

***DISCLAIMER #2:*** I haven't updated my app for WatchOS 2. I doubt this part of things changed, but it is possible.

Comment: Thanks will play around with that tonight, Just one question is what is originalInterfacecontroller? Where does that come from?

Comment: In your original post, you said, "I am attempting to pass an int to another interface, edit the int and give it back to the original interface." `originalInterfaceController` would be the one passing the int to the other IC and then receiving it back. In Watch apps, each interface is managed by a separate WKInterfaceController. Two have two interfaces, you must have two controllers. Does this make sense? Am I misunderstanding something about what you are attempting?

Comment: Ah it is my fault, In the original interface controller I am passing it using the pushControllerWithName and giving it the context of my variable. It's just trying to get it back that I'm having difficulty with and when I use the your self.originalInterfaceController (self.InterfaceController for me) it gives me the error "Property 'InterfaceController' not found on object of type 'SecondController'. So I was wondering how you got it to work. 

I Apologise for my inexperienced I am quite new to this. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Rohan, don't apologize for being new or not understanding. This is how people learn. If I didn't want to help you, I wouldn't. What you're doing shouldn't be hard, so we will get you over the hump. Would you throw more of your code into the original post? It would help me help you.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, Code that I use to receive the int in the second interface has been added and my extremely crude way of splitting it from a string.

Comment: Rohan, I continue to have difficulty following what you have defined where, and what is calling what. You do have two files, "InterfaceController.m" and "SecondController.m," correct? Will you please post each of them in the original post in two separate code blocks? As I read it now, it is difficult to determine what code is in which file, what variables are instance variables of which class, and the sequence of the methods that are called. I'm sorry I can't give you more. I'm really trying.

Comment: Please also include the header files for each .m file.

Comment: Sorry Matt, I have added the .h and .m files for both interfaces. I apologise for the slow replies, Have been quite busy lately. Thanks so much for the help and your patience.